# Cambiar letra a mayúscula con shell script

Tags: linux, bash

Necesito hacer un script que te pida introducir una letra minúscula mediante `read` y que con una tubería hacia `tr` cambie la letra minúscula por una mayúscula.

Con `case` tengo que decir dependiendo de si esa letra ahora mayúscula es A,B o C que en pantalla diga que es una curva y si es D,E o F una recta.

Este es el código que llevo actualmente:

```
read -p "introduce una letra minúscula" letra || tr '[a-e]' '[A-E]'
case $letra in 
  A|B|C) 
    echo "es curva" 
  ;;
  D|E|F)
    echo "es una recta"
  ;;
  *) 
    echo "no es ni curva ni recta"
esac
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solo veo que tu problemea en tu código era el uppercase ya que no se pasaba la letra a mayus para el case.Prueba con está forma **$letra | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z')**

```
#!/bin/bash


read -p "introduce una letra minúscula: " letra 


letra=$(echo $letra | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z')

echo "Letra introducida : $letra "
case $letra in 
  A|B|C) 
    echo "es curva" 
  ;;
  D|E|F)
    echo "es una recta"
  ;;
  *) 
    echo "no es ni curva ni recta"
esac
```

Ejecución:

```
> $ ./Test.sh introduce una letra minúscula: a
 Letra introducida : A 
es curva
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, me has resuelto la duda. Antes había intentado hasta hacer una redirección a otra variable pero ahora todo cobra más sentido. Tenga un bonito día :D

Answer (score 0):

Una alternativa a `tr` es el built-in `declare -u`

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -u letra
read -p "introduce una letra minúscula: " letra
...
```

que `declare -u` cualquier texto asignado a la variable "letra" la transforma en mayúsculas.

Otra alternativa es utilizar brace expansion.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "introduce una letra minúscula: " letra
case ${letra^^} in
...
```

donde la expansión `${letra^^}` vuelve esa variable en mayúsculas.

Una variante en **zsh** sería algo así:

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh

read "?introduce una letra minúscula: " letra
case ${letra:u} in
...
```